# How do I describe an image created using CSS?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

So for images, there's the alt attribute to tell people who can't view it what it is.

What if I have a bunch of divs styled in such a way that it creates an image? 
(Like a bunch of divs styled to look like a dice using CSS perspective and transforms).

How do I tell screen readers that "Hey! this is a dice".

Comment: try using title attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know so much about accessibility but perhaps the [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) element could be used?

You could use it together with the [`<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) element for a a visible caption. If you use Bootstrap and don't want it visible, you can use the `.sr-only` (screenreader only class).

You could also use the global attribute `title`.

Example:

```
<figure>
  <!-- your div elements with CSS here -->
  <figcaption>Hey, this is a dice!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

With invisible description (using Bootstrap):

```
<figure>
  <!-- your div elements with CSS here -->
  <figcaption class="sr-only">Hey, this is a dice!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Using the `title` attribute.

```
<figure title="Hey, this is a dice!">
  <!-- your div elements with CSS here -->
</figure>
```

But I don't know which is the most semantic or proper way in terms of accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell screen readers that "Hey! this is a dice".

Generally speaking, you don't (although you could use [aria-describedby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute)).

In most cases, the image will either be:

- Entirely decorative and thus not need alternative text because it doesn't convey information in the first place *or*
- Is conveying information other than "This is a dice" such as "This link points to an article in the games category"

So you need to consider the information you are trying to convey.

Then you have a number of options such as:

- Using a real image. Using CSS to create images is a clever hack, but it is a hack and does have drawbacks.
- Providing the information in text form as well as graphical form. As a bonus, this can be helpful to people who don't depend on screen readers but who have trouble interpreting the icon.
- Using an [aria-label](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label)

Answer (score -2):

My dear You can use Tooltip

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `<img>` element so they can't use `alt`.

Comment: The `<footer>` element [represents a footer for its nearest sectioning content or sectioning root element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) … which, again, they are not using.

Comment: A footer is not the same as an `alt` attribute. And there is no image as OP described. Also I wonder what `float` has to do with it all.

Comment: Updated the answer